# How many ways the json data can be send in post request of httpclient in java?

Tags: java, json, post, apache-httpclient-4.x

Explain all the types of sending json format
For example:
As Json File
As queryString
As entity

Comment: Json Format may any kind.. there is no specific number of format.
only two format which actually known is JSONObject and JSONArray.

you can declare your own type ... you can mix these object and made any kind of complicated JSONObject you need actually

Only You should take care of proper nesting of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are Various type of Format Sample you may see [here](https://adobe.github.io/Spry/samples/data_region/JSONDataSetSample.html).....

> Just Take a LOOK..

Comment: Thanks it helps me a lot